# need advice on Zend framework Application architecture, or say approach dealing with modules

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, architecture

Let me start with the things that I did and how am I using some things to get results

I have set up modular structure as:

```
application/
    /configs
    /layouts
    /models
    /modules
         /users
         /profile
             /frontend
             /backend
                 /controllers
                 /views
              ....
```

1. I write a plugin that does addes changes with FrontController->setModuleControllerDirectoryName()
   FrontController->addModuleDirectory()
   and It is all good I have a changed all the directories according weather admin page is requested in the url or not (it is some thing like /admin/some/some)
2. Let's say I have a single layout for anything that is related to Profile viewing , in this case the "Profile" module. The Profile layout is divided into three parts

   [alt text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2463/profileyw.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2463/profileyw.png)

In the layout I was pulling out the Profile/PhotoController 's index action with a action()

```
$this->action('index', 'photo', 'profile');
```

Then I have faced few issues 
1. Can get passed Params inside the Photo Controller when calling ( profile/profile/index);
2. found out that helper Action() is evil cause it starts another dispatching loop =)
 --- and now I am thinking that my approach on plugging in controllers modules into layout also evil =). 
anyhow how Should I deal with plugging in some controllers (another module controllers) into the layout ?

Comment: please anyone , Gordon where are you =)

Comment: Or is it a wrong place to ask ?  =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay to be honest your project structure is not clear enough like :

```
 /profile
             /frontend
             /backend
               /controllers
               /views
```

profile is a module so what is forntend and backend any way 
what i understand is : 
you are willing to execute the  Profile/PhotoController on the dashbaord layout 
I might be wrong but i guess 
**create a service or  class in your namespace  and action helper *or in your case it should be view helper*  to execute that newly created class**

you will find more info on [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-1-8-web-application-development/book) chapter 10 -  Page 295  - Services for cross module communication

Hopefully I made a clue